# Returning a value from a function nested subs sink subscription

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function with a nested subs sink subscription and I am not sure how to get that return value. I got undefined.

```
studentDate = this.getstudentDate(Id);
```

below is the nested subs sink subscription:

```
   getStudentDate(Id) {

let objs= {
  Id: studyId,
}

this.subs.sink = this.apiDataService.studyInfo(objs)
  .subscribe((obj) => {
      return obj.Date;
  })
```

}

Comment: `this.apiDataService.studyInfo(objs)` is most likely asynchronous, so you cannot return whatever value its subscription produces from the `getStudentDate()`. Then, returning something in the subscription won't go anywhere. That lambda is being called by observable and not by your function, so whatever is being returned from the lambda ends up in observable implementation, and it's not interested in whatever comes out of lambda. My guess is that you need to return some kind of observable from `getStudentDate()` and then subscribe to that from outside, but it's not clear what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly simple to convert the subscription to an promise and await the result:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const studentDate = await this.getstudentDate(Id);
}

getStudentDate(studyId) {
  const objs = {
    Id: studyId,
  };
  
  return this.apiDataService
    .studyInfo(objs)
    .pipe(
      map(obj => obj.Date)
    )
    .toPromise();
}
```

I also mapped the result to only return the Date.